# Comments box - Sorry this feature isn't available right now

Tags: facebook

I should to integrate comments box in my website. Actually, I'm in development environment (with IP address instead of domain name)

I have created my application and one test application. I have integrate Comments box as well (no facebook javascript error in my console)

But when I tried to post a comment, I got this error :

> Sorry, this feature isn't available right now An error occurred while
>   processing this request. Please try again later.

Even in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
I got the same error for this url.

I don't know what I missed or where looking for...

Thanks for your helps :)

Comment: Hmmm so strange, I think the are bug on facebook side.

If you try on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
With an ip address that doesn't works

With IP address and top level domain, that works

For exemple :

url 1 : http://198.252.206.140.stackoverflow/foo.html
==> OK

url 2 : http://198.252.206.140/foo.html
===> KO

url 3 : http://stackoverflow.com/foo.html
===> OK

Answer (score 0):

Go to developers.facebook and under your app make your app public,which is under the app review sidemenu.